# Como adicionar campos dinamicamente e vinculá-los à viewmodel no Asp.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Tenho um relacionamento de 1:N entre Pessoa e Contato. Na minha view, consigo listar todos os contatos de um cliente, quando o mesmo é aberto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso implementar o botão "Novo Contato" de forma que, quando clicado, adicione dinamicamente os campos (Tipo de Contato, Contato, Contato Principal, Detalhes e o Botão Excluir)...  Eu tentei fazer com Java Script e consegui, mas tive problemas com as "validations" que não funcionavam e o "combobox ContatoTipo" que não popula... Isso ocorre pq não consegui usar as tags do asp.net core asp-"validation-for" e "asp-items" no bloco de JavaScript...

Fiz um FOR para receber os dados do banco e as validations e combobox funcionam corretamente. O Problema está no bloco JS que não funcionam. Como faço isso funcionar no JavaScript?

```
@model Retaguarda.Application.ViewModels.Pessoa.PessoaViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "_PessoaContato";
}
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="div-contatos">

                @if (Model.PessoasContatosViewModel != null)
                {
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.PessoasContatosViewModel.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <div class="row align-items-center">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PessoasContatosViewModel[i].Id, new { @class = "hid-id" })
                                <label asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].ContatoTipoId" class="control-label sel-contatoTipo">Tipo de Contato</label>
                                <select asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].ContatoTipoId" asp-items="Model.ContatosTipos" data-plugin="selectpicker" title="Selecione uma opção" class="form-control show-tick show-menu-arrow sel-contatoTipo"></select>
                                <span asp-validation-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].ContatoTipoId" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].Contato" class="control-label txt-contato">Contato</label>
                                <input type="text" asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].Contato" class="form-control txt-contato" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].Contato" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
                                <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default">
                                    <input type="checkbox" asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].ContatoPrincipal" class="ckb-contatoPrincipal" checked autocomplete="off" />
                                    <label asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].ContatoPrincipal" class=" ckb-contatoPrincipal">Contato Principal</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <label asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].Detalhes" class="control-label txt-detalhes">Detalhes</label>
                                <textarea asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].Detalhes" class="form-control txt-detalhes"></textarea>
                                <span asp-validation-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].Detalhes" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-default btn-outline btn-remover-contato" data-id="@Model.PessoasContatosViewModel[i].Id." style="margin-top: 30px;"><i class="icon wb-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }


                }

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button id="btn-add-contato" type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-default btn-outline"><i class="icon wb-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Novo Contato</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<script>
    $(function () {
        var qtdContatos = 0;

        $("#btn-add-contato").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var blocoContato = '<div class="row align-items-center">' +
                '  <div class="col-md-2" >' +
                '     <label name="PessoaContatoViewModel[' + qtdContatos + '].ContatoTipoId" class="control-label sel-contatoTipo">Tipo de Contato</label>' +
                '    <select name="PessoaContatoViewModel[' + qtdContatos + '].ContatoTipoId" data-plugin="selectpicker" title="Selecione uma opção" class="form-control show-tick show-menu-arrow sel-contatoTipo"></select>' +
                ' </div >' +
                '<div class="col-md-4">' +
                ' <label name="PessoaContatoViewModel[' + qtdContatos + '].Contato" class="control-label txt-contato">Contato</label>' +
                '  <input type="text" name="PessoaContatoViewModel[' + qtdContatos + '].Contato" class="form-control txt-contato" />' +
                ' </div>' +
                ' <div class="col-md-2">' +
                ' <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>' +
                ' <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default">' +
                ' <input type="checkbox" name="PessoaContatoViewModel[' + qtdContatos + '].ContatoPrincipal" class="ckb-contatoPrincipal" checked autocomplete="off" />' +
                '<label for="PessoaContatoViewModel[' + qtdContatos + '].ContatoPrincipal class="ckb-contatoPrincipal">Contato Principal</label>' +
                '</div>' +
                ' </div>' +
                ' <div class="col-md-3">' +
                '<label name="PessoaContatoViewModel[' + qtdContatos + '].Detalhes" class="control-label txt-detalhes">Detalhes</label>' +
                '<textarea name="PessoaContatoViewModel[' + qtdContatos + '].Detalhes" class="form-control txt-detalhes"></textarea>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="col-md-1">' +

                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-default btn-outline btn-remover-contato" style="margin-top: 30px;"><i class="icon wb-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>' +
                ' </div>' +
                ' </div>';

            $("#div-contatos").append(blocoContato);
            qtdContatos++;
        });

        $("#div-contatos").on("click", ".btn-remover-contato", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $(this).parent().parent().remove();

            qtdContatos--;

            $("#div-contatos .row").each(function (indice, elemento) {
                $(elemento).find(".sel-contatoTipo").attr("name", "PessoaContatoViewModel[" + indice + "].ContatoTipoId");
                $(elemento).find(".txt-contato").attr("name", "PessoaContatoViewModel[" + indice + "].Contato");
                $(elemento).find(".ckb-contatoPrincipal").attr("name", "PessoaContatoViewModel[" + indice + "].ContatoPrincipal");
                $(elemento).find(".txt-detalhes").attr("name", "PessoaContatoViewModel[" + indice + "].Detalhes");
            });

        });

    });
</script>


@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Policy = "CanWritePessoaData")]
[Route("pessoa-gerenciar/editar-pessoa/{id:int}")]
public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var pessoaViewModel = _pessoaAppService.GetJoinById(id.Value);

    if (pessoaViewModel == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }       

    pessoaViewModel.PessoaGenericoViewModel.Filiais = PreencherFiliais();
    pessoaViewModel.ContatosTipos = PreencherContatodosTipos();
    return View(pessoaViewModel);

}
```

ViewModels:

```
public class PessoaViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Natureza")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Escolha uma Natureza")]
    public PessoaNatureza PessoaNatureza { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Natureza")]
    public string PessoaNaturezaDescricao { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Naturezas")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PessoasNaturezas { get; set; }

    public PessoaGenericoViewModel PessoaGenericoViewModel { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PessoaGenericoViewModel> PessoasGenericosViewModel { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ContatosTipos { get; set; }
    public List<PessoaContatoViewModel> PessoasContatosViewModel { get; set; }

    public PessoaFisicaViewModel PessoaFisicaViewModel { get; set; }
    public PessoaJuridicaViewModel PessoaJuridicaViewModel { get; set; }

    public PessoaViewModel()
    {
        PessoasNaturezas = ExtensaoDeEnumerador.EnumParaSelectListGenerico<PessoaNatureza>("U", PessoaNatureza.ToString()).OrderBy(x => x.Text);
        PessoaFisicaViewModel = null;
        PessoaJuridicaViewModel = null;
    }
}


public class PessoaContatoViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int PessoaId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Tipo de Contato")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Escolha um Tipo de Contato")]
    public int ContatoTipoId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Tipo de Contato")]
    public string ContatoTipoDescricao { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Tipos de Contato")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ContatosTipos { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Contato")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo Contato é obrigatório")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} deve ter no máximo {1} caracteres")]
    public string Contato { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Detalhes")]
    [MaxLength(150, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} deve ter no máximo {1} caracteres")]
    public string Detalhes { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Contato Principal")]
    public bool ContatoPrincipal { get; set; }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Inclua a sua viewmodel e a controller. Ps. dá para fazer só com javascript... mas dá mais trabalho. As validações não funcionaram porque você não está criando todos os elementos necessários. Mas acho que aproveitando o recurso de uma View Component dá para resolver de forma mais simples

Comment: Obrigado @Leandro Angelo. Eu atualizei o Post. Só para reforçar, minha viewmodel já está com os campos validados usando o dataannotations e o recurso javascript unibtrusive já está instalado... Só preciso fazer o que já funciona no bloco do FOR, usando javascript... :)

Comment: Dentro de PessoaViewModel está a propriedade PessoaContatoViewModel...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se adicionar puro `html` assim como está fazendo, não vai ter coisas importantes da sua model, como *DataAnnotations* por exemplo. Uma solução "mista" seria criar uma *Action* que devolva uma linha nova da sua model e através de uma chamada *Ajax* à essa action, pegar o conteúdo devidamente renderizado, e adicionar.

Para isso, transforme o bloco que deseja adicionar dinamicamente numa *PartialView*:

### ContatoPartial:

```
<div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PessoasContatosViewModel[@ViewBag.indice].Id, new { @class = "hid-id" })
        <label asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[@ViewBag.indice].ContatoTipoId" class="control-label sel-contatoTipo">Tipo de Contato</label>
        <select asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[@ViewBag.indice].ContatoTipoId" asp-items="Model.ContatosTipos" data-plugin="selectpicker" title="Selecione uma opção" class="form-control show-tick show-menu-arrow sel-contatoTipo"></select>
        <span asp-validation-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[@ViewBag.indice].ContatoTipoId" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[@ViewBag.indice].Contato" class="control-label txt-contato">Contato</label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[@ViewBag.indice].Contato" class="form-control txt-contato" />
        <span asp-validation-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[@ViewBag.indice].Contato" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
        <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default">
            <input type="checkbox" asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[@ViewBag.indice].ContatoPrincipal" class="ckb-contatoPrincipal" checked autocomplete="off" />
            <label asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[@ViewBag.indice].ContatoPrincipal" class=" ckb-contatoPrincipal">Contato Principal</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[@ViewBag.indice].Detalhes" class="control-label txt-detalhes">Detalhes</label>
        <textarea asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[@ViewBag.indice].Detalhes" class="form-control txt-detalhes"></textarea>
        <span asp-validation-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[@ViewBag.indice].Detalhes" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-default btn-outline btn-remover-contato" data-id="@Model.PessoasContatosViewModel[@ViewBag.indice].Id." style="margin-top: 30px;"><i class="icon wb-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Crie uma *Action* que retorne essa *Partial*:

```
public PartialViewResult NovoContato(int indice)
{
     ViewBag.indice= indice;
     return PartialView("ContatoPartial", new PessoasContatosViewModel());
}
```

Altere o javascript para fazer uma chamada *Ajax* para acionar a *Action*, e adicionar o conteúdo na página:

```
var itemIndex = $("#container input.iHidden").length; 
        var novoIndice = qtdContatos +1;      //suponho q já tenha calculado
        e.preventDefault();
        $.get("@Url.Action("NovoContato", "NomeDaController")/"+novoIndice ,function(data){
            $("#div-contatos").append(data);
        });
```

Com isso, a nova linha será renderizada pelo `ASP.Net`, e a chamada `ajax` permite que não seja necessário um *Post* da página.

Comment: Obrigado @Ricardo Pontual. Sua ajuda foi muito útil para criar as rows sem o uso do JS, mas além eu tive que fazer a partialview usando a model PessoaContatoViewModel e estou com dificuldades para criar índices nela pois ela não contém lista somente os fields padrão. Eu criei outro post com o problema... caso vc saiba como resolvê-lo... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/327732/como-criar-um-index-para-os-campos-de-uma-viewmodel-para-serem-adicionados-dinam

Comment: vou dar uma olha, a noite qdo tiver com mais calma vou dar uma revisada, já fiz isso umas vezes :)